# Python Download Roblox Data

Tags: python, roblox

I'm attempting to format json from the Roblox API. I have a names.txt that stores all of the names. This is how the file looks

```
rip_robson0007
Abobausrip
app_58230
kakoytochelik123
Ameliathebest727
Sherri0708
HixPlayk
mekayla_091
ddddorffg
ghfgrgt7nfdbfj
TheWolfylikedog
paquita12345jeje
hfsgfhsgfhgfhds
```

It stores a bunch of usernames seperated by a new line. The code is suppose to use the names and for each name get the JSON from this endpoint [https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username={name}](https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=%7Bname%7D) & format it as I have in my code. It always returns error 429 and doesn't save any of the data.

This is the code:

```py
import json
import requests
import time

# Read the names from the text file
with open("./txt/names.txt", "r") as f:
    names = f.read().split("\n")
    
# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the users
users = {}

# Iterate through the names
for name in names:
    time.sleep(5)
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username={name}")

    # Check the status code of the response
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to get data for {name}: {response.status_code}")
        continue

    # Try to parse the response as JSON
    try:
        user_data = response.json()
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Failed to parse JSON for {name}")
        continue

    # Extract the necessary information from the response
    user_id = user_data["Id"]
    username = user_data["Username"]
    avatar_uri = user_data["AvatarUri"]
    avatar_final = user_data["AvatarFinal"]
    is_online = user_data["IsOnline"]

    # Add the user's information to the dictionary
    users[user_id] = {
        "Id": user_id,
        "Username": username,
        "AvatarUri": avatar_uri,
        "AvatarFinal": avatar_final,
        "IsOnline": is_online
    }

# Save the dictionary to a JSON file
with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: It works for me. I think you have tried too many times, and the server may rate-limit your requests. Try a different IP address.

Comment: When you try the link multiple times manually, still it gives 429 error. 429 says you have sent too many requests. No issue in your code.

Comment: It works just fine for me as well just using it in my browser, it only has a problem when running the code.

Comment: This is not a Python issue. You clearly know what HTTP 429 means so this is something you need to be talking about in a Roblox forum. You may be able to overcome this if you have access to several proxies

Answer (score 1):

You can often overcome this with judicious use of proxies.

Start by getting a list of proxies from which you will make random selections. I have a scraper that acquires proxies from https://free-proxy-list.net

My list (extract) looks like this:-

```
http://103.197.71.7:80 - no
http://163.116.177.33:808 - yes
```

'yes' means that HTTPS is supported. This list currently contains 95 proxies. It varies depending on the response from my scraper

So we start by parsing the proxy list. Subsequently we choose proxies at random before trying to access the Roblox API. This may not run quickly because the proxies are not necessarily reliable. They are free after all.

```
from requests import get as GET, packages as PACKAGES
from random import choice as CHOICE
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE

PACKAGES.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
ROBLOX_API = 'https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username'
TIMEOUT = 1

def get_proxies():
    http, https = list(), list()
    with open('proxylist.txt') as p:
        for line in p:
            proxy_url, _, supports_https = line.split()
            _list = https if supports_https == 'yes' else http
            _list.append(proxy_url)
    return http, https

http, https = get_proxies()

def process(name):
    params = {'username': name.strip()}
    while True:
        try:
            proxy = {'http': CHOICE(http), 'https': CHOICE(https)}
            (r := GET(ROBLOX_API, params=params, proxies=proxy, timeout=TIMEOUT)).raise_for_status()
            if (j := r.json()).get('success', True):
                print(j)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            pass

with open('names.txt') as names:
    with TPE() as executor:
        executor.map(process, names)
```

In principle, the *while* loop in *process()* could get stuck so it might make sense to limit the number of retries.

This produces the following output:

```
{'Id': 4082578648, 'Username': 'paquita12345jeje', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 2965702542, 'Username': 'mekayla_091', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 4079018794, 'Username': 'app_58230', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 3437922948, 'Username': 'kakoytochelik123', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 4082346906, 'Username': 'Abobausrip', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 2988555289, 'Username': 'HixPlayk', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 3286921649, 'Username': 'Sherri0708', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 1441252794, 'Username': 'ghfgrgt7nfdbfj', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 4088896225, 'Username': 'ddddorffg', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 3443374919, 'Username': 'TheWolfylikedog', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 3980932331, 'Username': 'Ameliathebest727', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 3773237135, 'Username': 'rip_robson0007', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
{'Id': 4082991447, 'Username': 'hfsgfhsgfhgfhds', 'AvatarUri': None, 'AvatarFinal': False, 'IsOnline': False}
```